# .htaccess block outside access on local server except for certain URL's

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I currently have my local `.htaccess` on a MAMP server set up to block all incoming traffic from outside my local system;

```
<FilesMatch ".*">
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
</FilesMatch>
```

This works fine but I then use API's like PayPal that require access to your site for IPN's. Is it possible to keep the restriction on the rest of the site and allow outside access only to specific urls like `https://example.com/paypal_ipn`?

I understand I can just switch the restriction off when using IPN's but that's not what I'm looking for. Many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `mod_rewrite` based rules instead in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/paypal_ipn [NC]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^127\.0\.0\.1
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

This will block all requests that are not:

1. originating from localhost (`127.0.0.1`)
2. for `/paypal_ipn`

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm actually looking to do it the other way round. I want to block all access to the site from requests not originating from localhost, and allow access to all IP's only to certain URL's. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: No you didn't understand it right. This will block as you say i.e. **all access to the site from requests not originating from localhost except for few pages**

Comment: Ah perfect I see now. Works for me. Thanks for your help. Not sure why someone would downvote my question tho.

Comment: Question wasn't worth down voting and I have given my upvote to neutralize it. I am glad it worked for you.